# how to fix problem scheduled tasks with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My scheduled task is as follows
But the application does not respond  when i use `@Scheduled(cron="0 46 17  * * *")`
And when I use  `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000)` , When saving information on mongoDB The program gives an error

`[ scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.`

`: An unexpected error occurred during scheduled work.`
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

please help me for fix my cod .

```java
    @Scheduled(cron="0 46 17  * * *")
//  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    @RequestMapping("/closeAttendance}")
    public void cloceAttendance() {
        System.out.println("-1");
        AttendanceService attendanceService=new AttendanceService();
        Date date=attendanceService.getCurrentDate();
        System.out.println("1");
        List<Attendance> attendances=arepo.findByDate(date);
if(attendances!=null) {
        System.out.println("attendances"+attendances.size());
        System.out.println("2");
//  
        for(Attendance attendance:attendances) {
            System.out.println("3");
            attendance=attendanceService.closeAttendance(attendance);
            System.out.println("4");
            System.out.println("attendance"+attendance.getDate()+" "+ attendance.getPerson());
//          arepo.save(attendance);

        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: With the cron expression it will only run once a day. The fixed rate will run every 50 seconds. Let me guess the `NullPointerException` is right after the line where you create a new `AttendanceService` which should probably be injected by Spring instead of a new instance created by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The only thing that is missing is the **annotation** `@EnableScheduling`.

Use this **annotation** at **class level** and your code will work fine.

Please don't forgot to *up-vote* if this solution works for you.

Comment: I used this annotation to main class 
And I used the @Scheduled  in the my controller
But the program does not run with the `@Scheduled(cron="0 46 17  * * *")`, but runs with the 
 `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000)`
But in both cases the `arepo.save(attendance);` is not running

Comment: error is:   `[   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected  error occurred in scheduled task.`

Answer (score -1):

```
   Use the below code for your reference and do the changes according to your need
```

package com.winner.service;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling ;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
com.winner.etyping.domain.RegParentDomain;
import com.winner.etyping.domain.SchoolRegistrationDomain;
import com.winner.etyping.domain.StudentDomain;
@EnableScheduling
@Servic
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService{

    @Autowired
    private ClassService classserice;

    @Autowired
    private DivisionService div;

    @Autowired
    private RegParentService parent;

    @Autowired
    private SchoolregistrationService school;

    @Autowired
    private StudentDao studendao;





    @Transactional
    public List<StudentDomain> getByClassAndDivId(Integer classid, Integer div,Integer school) {
        return studendao.getByClassAndDivId(classid,div,school);
    }

    **@Scheduled(cron="0 0 10 * * ?")**
    @Transactional
    public void sendBirthdayWish() throws Exception {
        studendao.sendBirthdayWish();

    }

    @Transactional
    public void sendNotificationToClassStudent(ClassDomain classid, SchoolRegistrationDomain schoolid , String Notification) throws Exception {
        studendao.sendNotificationToClassStudent(classid,schoolid,Notification);

    }






}
```